# How to forward output of a command as function argument

Tags: batch-file, window, command

I need to forward the output of the `copy` command to `WRITELOG` function. is there anyway to do this? This is what I tired and not works

```
copy /y %source% %destination%>WRITELOG

:WRITELOG
if not "%1"=="" (
 echo %time% : %*>>%LOGFILE%
)
```

Comment: redirection (`>`) is made to redirect to a file (or device). You will either work with that file in your function or use `for /f` to catch the output of the command into a variable and use that with a `call` (which will work with a one-line-output only)

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion by [Stephan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) would be coded for example as:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "source=%~1"
set "destination=%~2"
set "LOGFILE=%TEMP%\CopyLog.txt"
for /F "delims=" %%L in ('copy /Y "%source%" "%destination%" 2^>nul') do (
    set "CopyOutput=%%L"
    if not "!CopyOutput:copied=!" == "%%L" echo %time% : %*>>%LOGFILE%
)
endlocal
```

For an explanation on how the used commands work, open a command prompt window, run there following commands and read help output for each command:

- `copy /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `set /?`

However, this solution is not good because of following reasons:

1. String `copied` in **IF** condition depends on language of command **copy**.
2. If the file(s) in source are found, but could not be copied to destination because destination is write-protected, the output of **copy** is `0 file(s) copied.` which is interpreted by this code as successful copy.

The second disadvantage could be avoided by using:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "source=%~1"
set "destination=%~2"
set "LOGFILE=%TEMP%\CopyLog.txt"
for /F "tokens=1,3" %%A in ('copy /Y "%source%" "%destination%" 2^>nul') do (
    echo %%A %%B
    if not "%%A" == "0" (
        if "%%B" == "copied." echo %time% : %*>>%LOGFILE%
    )
)
endlocal
```

But much better would be evaluating exit code of command **copy** which is **0** on success and greater 0 on error.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "source=%~1"
set "destination=%~2"
set "LOGFILE=%TEMP%\CopyLog.txt"
copy /Y "%source%" "%destination%" >nul 2>nul
if not errorlevel 1 echo %time% : %*>>%LOGFILE%
endlocal
```

See the Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576).

`if not errorlevel 1` means if exit code of previous command is NOT greater or equal 1 then ...
Or in other words if exit code of previous command is smaller than 1 then ...

Command **copy** never exits with a negative value like all internal commands of `cmd.exe` and nearly all console applications because **0** is standard for success and a value greater 0 is an indication for an error.